# how to use PHP for loop to write a multiple radio form?

Tags: php, html, forms, for-loop, radio-button

I write my code like this and it still does not work to produce a multiple radio forms. I try to use `fieldset` but still does not work. How can I solve this? `fieldset` with different ID supposes can help to make multiple forms right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

for($i = 1; $i<4; $i = $i+1){

   echo "
   <fieldset id = 'form$i'>
      <hr>
      <br>

      <legend> Question $i</legend>

      <br><br>

      <div class='radioBox'>
      <label>(A)
         <input type='radio' name='radio' required value='A'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>
      <label>(B)  
         <input type='radio' name='radio' required value='B'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>
      <label>(C) 
         <input type='radio' name='radio' required value='C'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>
      <label>(D)  
         <input type='radio' name='radio' required value='D'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>

      <br>
      </div>
      <br>
  </fieldset>
  ";
}
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but checkbox can choose more than one answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php for($i = 1; $i<4; $i++){
?>

   <fieldset id = 'form<?php echo $i; ?>'>
      <hr>
      <br>

      <legend> Question <?php echo $i; ?></legend>

      <br><br>

      <div class='radioBox'>
      <label>(A)
         <input type='radio' name='radio<?php echo $i; ?>' required value='A'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>
      <label>(B)  
         <input type='radio' name='radio<?php echo $i; ?>' required value='B'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>
      <label>(C) 
         <input type='radio' name='radio<?php echo $i; ?>' required value='C'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>
      <label>(D)  
         <input type='radio' name='radio<?php echo $i; ?>' required value='D'>
         <span class='checkmark'></span>
      </label><br>

      <br>
      </div>
      <br>
  </fieldset>

<?php } ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is same as my previous code but yours can work. I wonder why. BTW thanks

Comment: You are welcome.Please mark this question as answered so that we can close it.